# Azure Cosmos Db with Docker token issue

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb

I am using document db with my console application. I am able to access document db with my project running without any issue. But when I am running my console application with docker locally on windows as windows container its not able to access document db.

I am getting following error :

> The authorization token is not valid at the current time. Please create 
>   another token and retry (token start time: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 20:54:57 GMT,
>   token expiry time: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 21:09:57 GMT,
>   current server time: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 08:24:47 GMT).
>   ActivityId: a3e015e6-a4bb-47dc-bf24-c7ceacad317c, 
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.21.0.0, Windows/10.0.16299 documentdb-
>   netcore-sdk/1.8.1

It seems issue with time sync problem.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue, and here is the reply from Microsoft

Cosmosdb authorization token is generated for a time period between Now – 1 minute to Now + 15 minutes. The -1 was to account for clock drift between client machines and servers (which are synchronized).

The fact that you’re seeing this error clearly shows that we should have allowed for a longer time window to account for real world clock drifts, and we will increase this to -5 minutes in an upcoming service release.

Meanwhile, a workaround that might help you is to adjust your machines time back by 2 minutes.

Adjusting my machine time back by 2 minutes fixed the problem and allowed me to access my Costmosdb account.  Hopefully the permanent fix will be deployed soon.

**[Related Issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1b75f98c-5b99-4224-8a20-8d90752019d5/the-authorization-token-is-not-valid-at-the-current-time?forum=azurecosmosdb)**

Comment: Was this for a Resource Token? or Master Token?